# “Object variable or with block variable not set” Error coming

Tags: excel, vba

**I'm running my code to find data from a workbook and synchronizing it with another workbook and upon running macro, I am receiving this error. Can anyone please help? Thanks**

I'm running my code to find data from a workbook and synchronizing it with another workbook and upon running macro, I am receiving this error. Can anyone please help? Thanks

I'm running my code to find data from a workbook and synchronizing it with another workbook and upon running macro, I am receiving this error. Can anyone please help? Thanks

[image: IMG1]

```
Sub FindData(wbW As Workbook, WbD As Workbook, ByVal dCol As Long)
    Dim wSh As Long
    Dim dSh As Long
    Dim w As Long, d As Long, c As Long
    Dim col As String
    Dim co As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim var As Range, coCl As Range
    Dim lastColD As Long, lastColW As Long, lastRowW
    Dim wsW As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet
    Dim dc As Long, wc As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    Debug.Print WbD.Name
    Debug.Print wbW.Name
    If wbW.Name = ws.Range("A2") & ".xlsx" And WbD.Name = ws.Range("A4") & ".xlsx" Then
      col = "D"
    Else
      If wbW.Name = ws.Range("A2") & ".xlsx" And WbD.Name = ws.Range("A5") & ".xlsx" Then
        col = "G"
      Else
        If wbW.Name = ws.Range("A2") & ".xlsx" And WbD.Name = ws.Range("A6") & ".xlsx" Then
          col = "J"
        Else
          If wbW.Name = ws.Range("A3") & ".xlsx" And WbD.Name = ws.Range("A7") & ".xlsx" Then
            col = "M"
          Else
            If wbW.Name = ws.Range("A3") & ".xlsx" And WbD.Name = ws.Range("A8") & ".xlsx" Then
              col = "P"
            End If
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End If
    wSh = ws.Range(col & 1).End(xlDown).Row
    dSh = WbD.Worksheets.Count
    For w = 3 To wSh        'Working file sheets listed in macro workbook Sheet1
      Set wsW = wbW.Worksheets(ws.Range(col & w).Value)
      lastColW = wsW.Cells(2, wsW.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
      lastRowW = wsW.Cells(wsW.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
      For c = 5 To lastRowW       'Companies in working file
        co = wsW.Range("B" & c)
        For d = 1 To dSh    'Data worksheet
          Set coCl = Nothing
          Set wsD = WbD.Worksheets(d)
          If wsD.Range("A1") = co Then
             Set coCl = wsD.Range("A1")
          Else
            If wsD.Range("A2") = co Then
              Set coCl = wsD.Range("A2")
            End If
          End If
          If Not coCl Is Nothing Then
            lastColD = wsD.Cells(coCl.Offset(1, 0).Row, wsD.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    '        If WbD.Name = "2005-2010.xlsx" Then
    '          yr = "5-10"
    '        End If
            If lastColD = 1 Then
              lastColD = wsD.Cells(coCl.Offset(2, 0).Row, wsD.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
              Set coCl = coCl.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
            Set var = wsD.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Find(ws.Range(col & w).Offset(0, 1), , xlValues, xlPart, , , False)
            'Debug.Print wsD.Name
            For dc = 2 To lastColD
              For wc = 5 To lastColW
                'Debug.Print wsD.Cells(coCl.Offset(1, 0).Row, dc).Value
                'Debug.Print wsW.Cells(2, wc).Value
                If wsD.Cells(coCl.Offset(1, 0).Row, dc).Value = wsW.Cells(2, wc).Value Then
                'wsD.Range(wsD.Cells(var.Row, 2), wsD.Cells(var.Row, lastColD)).Copy Destination:=wsW.Cells(c, dCol)
    '              Debug.Print wsD.Name
    '              Debug.Print wsD.Cells(var.Row, dc).Value
                  wsW.Cells(c, wc).Value = wsD.Cells(var.Row, dc).Value
                End If
              Next
            Next
            Exit For
          End If

        Next
      Next
    Next
    'Debug.Print WbD.Name
    'Debug.Print wbW.Name
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please, post only the piece of code with error - no need for all the code...

Comment: Which line errors out?

Comment: @JohnyL It's Line 144 Col 1

Comment: *Line 144* You want us to count the lines? :)

Comment: @JohnyL Sorry:)

Comment: @JohnyL Description of Line 144: "wsW.Cells(c, wc).Value = wsD.Cells(var.Row, dc).Value"

Comment: What happens if you can't find the value you're looking for when you set `var`?  I'm going to bet that when you get that error, if you did `debug.print var.address` before that line, you'll error because `var` didn't find a match.

Comment: @BruceWayne can you please edit the code in the Answer?

Comment: What answer? I am suggesting a way to add that to your current code to test it.

Comment: You set `var` variable, but do not check whether it's `Nothing` or not. Check in debug mode whether it is so.

Answer (score 0):

What @BruceWayne was suggesting, is you need to verify `Find` function was successful before using it later on.

```
Set Var = wsD.Range("A3").CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Find(ws.Range(col & w).Offset(0, 1), , xlValues, xlPart, , , False)

If Not Var Is Nothing Then ' <-- make sure Find function was able to find a match
    ' rest of your code goes here

Else
    ' raise an error message
    MsgBox "Unable to find " & ws.Range(col & w).Offset(0, 1) & " in the range specified", vbCritical, "Error!"
End If
```

---

Also, you can change your multiple `If` with `And` to `If` and `Select Case`, like in the code below:

```
If wbW.Name = ws.Range("A2") & ".xlsx" Then

    Select Case WbD.Name ' using Select case can clear and simpify your code
        Case ws.Range("A4") & ".xlsx"
            col = "D"

        Case ws.Range("A5") & ".xlsx"
            col = "G"

        Case ws.Range("A6") & ".xlsx"
            col = "J"

        Case ws.Range("A7") & ".xlsx"
            col = "MD"

        Case ws.Range("A8") & ".xlsx"
            col = "P"

    End Select
End If
```